# Convert React Native View to HTML

Tags: react-native, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

In my React Native app I want to allow the user to select one of a few variations of pre-built templates, make modifications to it and then have the ability to export the `<html>`ised version of it to the DB.

The user could, for example, add some content in an identified area(in a `<TextInput` perhaps), maybe change a placeholder image by uploading one, perhaps even make slight changes to the styling (move an image to the left/right/center etc) and can then save the modifications as HTML content.

Example

```
<View style={{flex: 1,....}> 
    <TextInput value ="Some content".../>
    <View> 
        <TextInput value ="Nested View.../>
        <Image ... />
    </View> 
</View>
```

The exported HTML would now be

```
<div style="flex: 1">
    <p> Some content  </p>
    <div>
        <p> Nested View </p>
        <img src='' />
    </div>
</div>
```

There are a few libraries that reliably translate `html` to react native views and components but i am looking for the other way around.

One way would be to use `WebView` and go the `contenteditable` route. This is the approach taken by most of the react-native specific WYSWYG rich text editors. I tried a few of these RTEs but did find some issue or the other with all of those that i tried, including non-optimal UX. Additionally, a big requirement is resizing images(this of course presumes the ability to upload, and then select the image) once inserted. I haven't found any editor that does this. TinyMCE running in a `webview` has the best support but does not have the regular resize-via-hanldles option, but did seem to have the ability to resize via the image dialog by changing the width/height numbers. Another issue noticed was videos not seeming toplay inside of a `webview` from some early emulator testing. The audio seems to work fine however.

My plan was to make a simple hybridized editor. Pre-built templates can be chosen by the user. The user can tap on the text content area of the chosen template and modify the content(maybe in a separate scene). Similarly modifying the image will have its own dedicated scene.  Finally the resultant HTML(if reliably possible) can be exported to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using TinyMCE since i got a reasonably ok mobile experience from early testing.

A possible solution to reliably render the JSX to HTML could be as simple as using [`renderToStaticMarkup` or `renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) on the server after making any necessary changes (like in my example, the text inputs may need to be interpreted differently).

Does [work on the client](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#overview) as well.

EDIT:

React Native cannot import `react-dom-server`. So a server solution would be the only option at the moment. See [issue comments here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3859) that also includes a link to a package that converts JSX to JSON.